# Interface 8051 DC motor using a DAC

Tags: amplifier, dac, 8051, circuit-design

I want to interface 8051 to a double gear box kit with comes with a dc motor. The motor spec is : "3-6 volts and draws up to a few amps"
The DAC is MAXIM 512  : And as per the data sheet, this is what i find : "
The latched digital output (LOUT) has a 1.6mA source capability while maintaining a (VDD - 0.4V) output level. With a 1.6mA sink current, the output voltage is guaranteed to be no more than 0.4V. "

And I need an amplifier to connect the DAC output to the motor. But how to design the amplifier circuit for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you intend to try driving the motor with a varying voltage to control it's speed then you would need a motor driver amplifier.

A much better way to work this problem would be to simply power the motor from a 3->6V supply and use a MOSFET transistor rated for "more than a few amps" as a switch to permit turning the motor on and off at a very high rate.

Use the 8051 with a timer or software to generate the very high rate at which the MODFET is turned on and off. Now when you generate such waveform vary the amount of time that the motor is off versus on. This will change the speed of the motor!! This technique is called PWM (pulse width modulation).

When you begin to research PWM techniques to control motor speed you will also come to learn how to connect such driver to the 8051 and at what types of frequency you should be using for the PWM waveform.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. I am using a AT89C51RC2, so I can generate a PWM using the PCA module in that. And I can use it to control the motor by varying the duty of PWM. But I was not sure about the amplifier to be connected between the DAC and the motor. Can the amplifier circuit be as simple as using a transistor or should I go for a Full bridge IC ?